# Adding a vertex between two vertices that sticks to an object?

Tags: modeling, vertices

So, i'm following this tutorial, and there comes a part where the person selects two vertices and creates a new one in between them that sticks to an edge between those vertices.

[image]
[image]

I have no idea how to do this and can't seem to find an answer. The best i could find was selecting both vertices and pressing F, but that simply creates a new edge that goes through the object.

[image]

Would appreciate some help!
Here is the link, it happens at 2:13
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hCrZWJphLE&ab_channel=TopChannel1on1

Comment: Press J to create an edge, not F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that this is your topology and you want to create an edge between these 2 vertices:

[image]

If you press <kbd>F</kbd> it will create an edge but it won't go across the existing faces:

[image]

You need to press <kbd>J</kbd> to create an edge that will go across the faces. Note that you could also use the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate):

[image]